# SSL Error installing rbenv on Mac Catalina

Tags: ruby, macos, ssl, homebrew, rbenv

I'm trying to install rbenv on Mac Catalina Version 10.15.7 using homebrew and I get this error:

```
gaston.ramos@AR-IT10128 ~ % brew install rbenv
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 4 formulae.

==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/autoconf-2.69.catalina.bottle.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/gaston.ramos/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c473cc5dd3e84f64b99973078d9d9caae87e7810e6e771008e63d651bbe8007f--autoconf-2.69.catalina.bottle.4.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/archive/v20201221.tar.gz
##O#- #
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
Error: Failed to download resource "ruby-build"
Download failed: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/archive/v20201221.tar.gz
```

Any idea on how to solve this? It seems that there is an SSL error when brew tries to download ruby-build

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a curl certificate error. Do you have your curl certificates installed? Do you have problems with other SSL/TLS connections? Are you behind a proxy? Have you tried updating ruby-build and/or rbenv?

Answer (score 3):

Use a different mirror

```
foo@bar$ env HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN=https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/homebrew-bottles brew install rbenv
```